# How to do a simple http post/ get with header using erlang (without a library if possible)?

Tags: erlang

I'm new to the erlang ecosystem and I'm looking for the equivalent of this curl command

```
curl 'http://localhost/api/foo/' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer abc123'
```

I'd like to stay as "core lib" focused as possible (ie- this example in ruby works out of the box on the REPL)

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://localhost/api/foo/')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['Authorization'] = 'Bearer abc123'
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
    http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

Comment: There are some examples in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6173493/113848).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [inets](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/index.html). This is part of standard Erlang distribution, that lets you send get and post requests with custom headers.

[How to use inets as http client](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_client.html)

And the code to perform, what you need:

```
inets:start(),
Url = "http://localhost/api/foo/",
AuthHeader = {"Authorization", "Bearer abc123"},
{ok, {{Version, 200, ReasonPhrase}, Headers, Body}} =
    httpc:request(get,
                  {Url, [AuthHeader]},
                  [],
                  []),
io:format("~s", [Body]).
```